# Quasi-Poisson - Goodness of fit

Tags: self-study, goodness-of-fit, quasi-likelihood

Can I use likelihood ratio chi-squared tests to test the goodness of fit for quasi-Poisson models?

Comment: It is possible (like, I think R will do it if you ask), but I don't think it is totally appropriate because the quasi poisson technically has no likelihood because it has no probability distribution.

Comment: Thanks @DemetriPananos. Yes, when I try to compute it in R it all works fine, which I found confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly: no. Goodness-of-fit tests against an unspecified alternative (e.g., testing either the sum of squares of Pearson residuals or the residual deviance against the upper tail of a $\chi^2_{n-p}$ distribution) depend on the assumption of a fixed mean-variance relationship with no adjustable scale parameters.  Once you estimate a dispersion parameter (as in quasi-likelihood), you've essentially soaked up all of the lack of fit into a single parameter. You can compute a pseudo-$R^2$ of some sort, but these are not associated with a particular test.

With quasi-likelihood fits, you're in a similar situation to fitting a linear/ordinary least-squares model; there are plenty of things you can do to *examine* the goodness of fit (e.g. plot residuals vs fitted to look for bias; scale-location plot to look for heteroscedasticity; Cook's distance/leverage plot to look for outliers), and you can if you like test particular aspects of the fit (e.g. can you reject the hypothesis that the residuals are Normally distributed? [although [many people consider this a bad idea](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)]), but there is no overall goodness-of-fit test.

You'll notice that many statistical procedures rely on tests of *relative* goodness of fit (likelihood ratio test, Wald $t$/$F$ test, AIC and other information criteria ...) but they usually start with a rather vague statement that the initial fit (e.g. the most complex one) should be "good enough" ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helped me a lot in understanding more about quasi-likelihood fits and how to make sure that the model is a good fit.